# Deleted cookies aren't deleted properly and still sent with requests

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

TestCafe Version: 2.1.0

I delete cookies based on user actions on my website client side as following:

```
document.cookie = "MY_COOKIE=; path=/; max-age=0;"
```

This works fine on manual tests. Unfortunately, in my TestCafe tests the cookies aren't deleted and remain in the following form (output of `await t.getCookies()` in test code):

```
[{
  name: 'MY_COOKIE',
  domain: 'xyz.com',
  path: '/',
  expires: undefined,
  maxAge: undefined,
  value: '',
  secure: false,
  httpOnly: false,
  sameSite: 'none'
},
...]
```

I also attached a `RequestLogger` and can see that the "deleted" cookies are also still sent in successive requests with an empty value to the server.

I found this [similar issue](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/5929) which has been fixed and adjusted the referenced [example](https://github.com/ghost23/testcafe-cookie-test) which can be used to reproduce the behaviour:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>DemoCookie</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="login">Login</button><button id="logout">Logout</button>
    <script>
      document.getElementById("login").addEventListener("click", function () {
        document.cookie = "MY_COOKIE=Hello; path=/; max-age=2592000";
      });

      document.getElementById("logout").addEventListener("click", function () {
        document.cookie = "MY_COOKIE=; path=/; max-age=0";
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
import { Selector, ClientFunction } from "testcafe";

fixture`Test cookies`.page`http://localhost:8080/index.html`;

const getCookie = ClientFunction(() => document.cookie);

test(`expect a deleted cookie to be gone`, async (t) => {
  const loginButton = Selector("#login");
  const logoutButton = Selector("#logout");

  await t.expect(await getCookie()).eql("");
  await t.click(loginButton);
  await t.navigateTo("/");
  await t.expect(await getCookie()).eql("MY_COOKIE=Hello");

  await t.click(logoutButton);
  await t.navigateTo("/");
  await t.expect(await getCookie()).eql("");
}).disablePageCaching;
```

The last `expect` of the test fails as value is `"MY_COOKIE="` instead of `""`.

Thanks a lot for your support!

Comment: I re-checked the mentioned example, and it works fine with the latest testcafe version. Make sure that you use the latest version because in the initial example, there is only 1.10.1.

Comment: @Aleksey Thanks for your reply. Did you check my provided test above or only the one from the referenced old example GitHub project? It definitely fails if you do requests to the server as with the two contained `t.navigateTo("/")` commands in my test. I tested for TestCafe versions `2.1.0` and `1.20.1`. Without server interaction it works fine.

Comment: @Aleksey After diving a bit into the hammerhead code and trying around, I think the issue is that a max age of 0 isn't added to piped cookie name in the browser. Therefore, `src/client/sandbox/cookie/index.ts:142` is `false` and cookie is not deleted. E.g. `document.cookie="MY_COOKIE=; path=/; max-age=0;"` is transformed to cookie name `c|LSa4mX2Q0|MY_COOKIE|localhost|%2F||lbdkucmu|` (value at index 7 interpreted as maxAge in hammerhead is missing), whereas `document.cookie="MY_COOKIE=; path=/; max-age=1;"` is transformed to `c|LSa4mX2Q0|MY_COOKIE|localhost|%2F||lbdkucmu|1` (maxAge added).

Comment: @Aleksey The reason for this issue is in `src/utils/cookie.ts:70` as a max age of 0 evaluates to `false` and therefore an empty string is added for `maxAge` in line 72 instead of `0`.

Comment: You're right, I checked the example and first didn't notice the difference, but now I see it. I managed to reproduce the issue. A [PR](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-hammerhead/pull/2818) with a fix already exists.

Comment: @Aleksey Thanks a lot! However, I tested the changes with TestCafe `2.2.0-rc.1` and it doesn't work yet if you "delete" multiple cookies (in my case around 30). Only the first one or two cookies are really deleted. For the others nothing happens. I debugged again and think a "timing" issue occurs in `syncCookie` function. If I add `&& maxAge > 0` to the "if statement" in `src/client/sandbox/cookie/index.ts` line 142 it works. Can you have a look again please?

Comment: I see. There is a [PR with a fix](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-hammerhead/pull/2830). It will be merged and published in the nearest release after 2.2.0.

Comment: @Aleksey Perfect, thanks a lot! I'll re-test when it's released.